# How to access a prototype's parent this from within a method's function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this class/function

```
function Menu()
{
  this.closetimer = 0;
  this.dropdown = 0;
}

Menu.prototype.menuTimer = function()
{
  this.closetimer = setTimeout(function()
  {
    this.menuClose();
  }, this.timeout);
}

Menu.prototype.menuClose = function()
{
  if(this.dropdown) this.dropdown.css('visibility','hidden');
}
```

I want to call the function `menuClose()` which is part of the Menu class, but I think this code actually tries to call `menuClose()` from the `closetimer` object.

How do I reference `menuClose()` from the Menu object from within `menuTimer()`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) callback, `this` refers to `window`, just keep a reference like this:

```
Menu.prototype.menuTimer = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.closetimer = setTimeout(function(){
        self.menuClose();
    }, this.timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to bind the inner function.

```
Menu.prototype.menuTimer = function(){
 this.closetimer = setTimeout(function(){
  this.menuClose();
 }.bind(this), this.timeout);
}
```

```
Menu.prototype.menuTimer = function(){
 this.closetimer = setTimeout(this.menuClose.bind(this), this.timeout);
}
```

Comment: Could this be written as `setTimeout(this.menuClose.bind(this), this.timeout)`?

Comment: You are absolutely right and I have updated it to show. It is by far the best solution. Give me all the votes!

Comment: This does make you sound a bit greedy :-)

Comment: the equivalent to prototype's bind function in jQuery is $.proxy. Very useful.

Comment: And they say jQuery is shorter to write! :-P

Answer (score 4):

you define a reference to the Menu (this) while you have access to it..

```
Menu.prototype.menuTimer = function(){
    var _self = this;
    this.closetimer = setTimeout(function(){
        _self.menuClose();
    }, this.timeout);
}
```

Comment: You should use `var _self` to guard against collisions with the global namespace.